# Intellij shows that my package doesn't exists.. but it exists?

Tags: intellij-idea, package, exists

Intellij shows an error that my mates that have pulled the project from github don't have so I really don't know why it is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jxh0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to my problem.

I went to "edit configuration" and I add a Maven configuration. Then I had to write "clean install" on command line and run it. It has fix my problem.